# Webpack + Angular 5 + Worker Loader + Karma

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-runner, web-worker

Im trying to setup an Angular project with Worker Loader. I am able to run the app but failed at running karma! Here is my approach:

1. Created project with `ng new webpack-worker-loader-karma` -> `ng serve` and `ng test` works
2. Added webpack `worker-loader` to project `npm i -D worker-loader`
3. Created worker typescript file `src/app/simple-loader.ts`
4. Created worker type definitions in `src/typings.d.ts`:

   ```
   declare module 'worker-loader?inline!*' {
     class WebpackWorker extends Worker {
     constructor();
   }

   export default WebpackWorker;
   }
   ```
5. Added code for instantiation of worker in `src/app/app.component.ts` -> `ng serve` returns this error:

   ```
   ERROR in ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src!./src/app/simple-worker.ts
   Module build failed: Error: @ngtools/webpack is being used as a loader but no `tsConfigPath` option nor AotPlugin was detected. You must provide at least one of these.
       at Object.ngcLoader (/[path]/webpack-worker-loader-karma/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:617:19)
   ```

   `
6. Had to set the tsConfigPath in webpack.config.js. So I ejected the project and changed the config:

   ```
   {
       "test": /\.ts$/,
       "loader": "@ngtools/webpack",
       "options": {
         "tsConfigPath": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
       }
   }
   ```

npm start -> works!

npm test -> error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src!./src/app/simple-worker.ts
    Module build failed: Error: @ngtools/webpack is being used as a loader but no `tsConfigPath` option nor AotPlugin was detected. You must provide at least one of these.
        at Object.ngcLoader (/[path]/webpack-worker-loader-karma/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/loader.js:617:19)
```

I think I have to set the tsConfigPath for karma. But don't know how. Any ideas?

I published the project on github:

https://github.com/kappaj/webpack-worker-loader-karma

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in Ionic (based on Angular).
I added "module" section to karma.conf.js

```
webpack: { 
  node: { 
    fs: 'empty' 
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          loader: "@ngtools/webpack",
          options: {
            tsConfigPath: "./src/tsconfig.spec.json",
          }
        },
        { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
        { test: /\.html$/, use: 'html-loader' },
        { test: /\.svg$/, use: 'html-loader' }
    ]
  }
}
```

After this `npm run test` works!